# "Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside inner class" How do I maniopulate a TextView depending on the status of a Checkbox?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

While I am well aware that it isn't possible for me to refer to a non-final variable inside my onClick method, I am interested in knowing how I solve the problem I am currently faced with.

I have an ArrayAdapter. If a user presses the checkbox an AsyncTask and the user either subscribes or unsubscribes himself to a queue, depending on whether the checkbox is checked or not.

I want this status to be reflected in each item in the text of my txtStatus TextView. How do I  set the text of a TextView depending on the status of a Checkbox?

Here is part of the code from my getView method :

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View row = convertView;

    final CheckBox queueCBox;
    userControl = new UserController(context);
    final String queueName = data[position].label; 
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        final QueueHolder holder = new QueueHolder();
        holder.queuecbox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.queues_item_checkbox);
        queueCBox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.queues_item_checkbox);
        holder.txtLabel = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.queues_item_label);
        holder.txtStatus = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.queues_item_status);

        holder.queuecbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                final String[] param = new String[1];
                param[0] = queueName;

                if(queueCBox.isChecked())
                {
                    holder.txtStatus.setText("Tilmeldt");
                    Log.d("ClickTest","SWITCH ON");
                    new JoinQueueTask().execute(param);


                }   
                else
                {
                    holder.txtStatus.setText("Frameldt");
                    Log.d("ClickTest","SWITCH OFF");
                    new LeaveQueueTask().execute(param);
                }   
            }
        });
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        final QueueHolder holder = (QueueHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    QueueItem queue = data[position];
    String name = queue.label.replace("-", " "); 
    holder.txtLabel.setText(name);    // holder cannot be resolved
    holder.queuecbox.setChecked(queue.value);  // holder cannot be resolved

    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep your holder the way it is. Just for setting the onClickListener, try doing this,

```
QueueHolder holder = null;
if(row == null)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    holder = new QueueHolder();
    holder.queuecbox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.queues_item_checkbox);
    queueCBox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.queues_item_checkbox);
    holder.txtLabel = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.queues_item_label);
    holder.txtStatus = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.queues_item_status);
    row.setTag(holder);
}
else
{
    holder = (QueueHolder)row.getTag();
}

QueueItem queue = data[position];
String name = queue.label.replace("-", " "); 
holder.txtLabel.setText(name);    // holder cannot be resolved
holder.queuecbox.setChecked(queue.value);  // holder cannot be resolved

final QueueHolder fianlHolder = holder;

finalHolder.queuecbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            final String[] param = new String[1];
            param[0] = queueName;

            if(queueCBox.isChecked())
            {
                finalHolder.txtStatus.setText("Tilmeldt");
                Log.d("ClickTest","SWITCH ON");
                new JoinQueueTask().execute(param);


            }   
            else
            {
                finalHolder.txtStatus.setText("Frameldt");
                Log.d("ClickTest","SWITCH OFF");
                new LeaveQueueTask().execute(param);
            }   
        }
    });
return row;
}
```

Comment: If I do this then holder cannot be resolved when I try to set the text of the label and the status of the checkbox  later in the method .
        holder.txtLabel.setText(name);
        holder.queuecbox.setChecked(queue.value);

Comment: Have you tried doing it? As far as i know, in this case your holder object becomes final and not the member variables of holder. I could be wrong about the 'final' part.

Comment: Yes. I edited my original post with the entire getView(). Look at the last couple lines

Comment: ahh! Sorry I messed it up a bit. I am editing my answer with what I did.

Comment: Great. Will be sure to check it out.

Comment: try the updated code. What you do is instead of creating a final object. create a normal object and then create a final reference to it. I'll help you make it work coz I have faced this issue before and it works for me now.